# How to remove braces from an array in objective C?

Tags: ios

```
NSMutableArray*array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"d", @"r", nil];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"msg"
                                                message:[array Description] 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

1. Output should be like
   a 
   d
   r
2. Not like
   (a 
   d
   r
   )

Comment: You're getting lots of downvotes and closevotes on this question, Akshay.  Could you add more detail explaining what you are trying to do?  I don't see any braces in that code, either.

Comment: Thanx for editing the question format.Thanx in advance if any one answer for this question.

Comment: already replaced. Solved ?

Comment: i want how to remove brace if we show this array in alert view.

Comment: out put should be like this    a d r   not like (a d r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use `NSString` for this purpose.

But if you insist on using `NSMutableArray` then do something like this.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil];
NSString *joinedString = [arr componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"msg"
                                                message:joinedString
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an NSArray description to an NSString parameter. This is where the braces come from. If you send a description message to an array, you will get back a string with all objects in an array enclosed with 'your' braces.

I am not sure what are you actually trying to achieve here. Message should be an NSString object like @"Invalid input".

If you want output a d r, I would combine objects of array into single string:

```
NSMutableArray*array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"d", @"r", nil];

NSString *combinedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", array[0], array[1], array[2]];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"msg"
                                                message:combinedString
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Comment: Your answer is right.But if have an array count 20 then how we solve this problem by dynamically providing index value.If we provide  object at index to an array  using  for loop then it will always pick last value.

Comment: i got my answer.Thanx martin.

Comment: I was about to provide code to dynamically construct the combinedString in a for-in loop, but the componentsJoinedByString is more elegant solution. But you obviously can iterate throgh the array and do whatever you want with each object. array.count will be your number of objects, but using for-in loop, you don't even have to care about the index. And if you need for whatever reasone, you can always ask for it in [array indexOfObject:item].